# Firebase retrieve data from a list of children without knowing the keys (Web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, server, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a web application that allows some users to send others push notifications. The list of users "subscribed" to any one user is stored in a firebase database, the structure is as follows;

```
senderUserID
    senderSubscribers
        subscriberOneID
            token: subToken
        subscriberTwoID
            token: subToken
        subscriberThreeID
            token: subToken
```

Basically I need to store the list of tokens in an array in order to use each of them to specify the clients receiving a push notification.

Here is my javaScript that returns the subscriber list 'Node'. In my case senderSubscribers is actually 'players'

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/'+currentUserId+'/players/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var allPlayersNode = snapshot.val();
        console.log(allPlayersNode);
});
```

Console.log looks something like

```
firstUserID:Object
    regID: the first subscribers token
secondUserID:Object
    regID: the second subscribers token
```

JSON code:

```
 "emails" : {
    "kylebehiels@hotmail" : "vlHVHcIetlZp7zS8mm6GcwoFRsB3",
    "test@gmail" : "hJuVfpGTJvRyP4qsA6xyyvgQDay1"
  },
  "users" : {
    "hJuVfpGTJvRyP4qsA6xyyvgQDay1" : {
      "email" : "test@gmail.com",
      "first_name" : "kyle",
      "games" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      },
      "last_name" : "behiels",
      "practices" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      },
      "regid" : "c_z_KWeWorU:APA91bHORVZqSph-HikfxtO2XjvMnwudIymORoSm9t3gupKZ1fFIZCLxGUbX5dsrYooHHpeEiPXhcXEMu5Eo5-nwF8bBjw-OTwSbn_rujTuPVaCDOXUKp9mzIYqeZq7SFMaWssZfyKj7",
      "workouts" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      }
    },
    "vlHVHcIetlZp7zS8mm6GcwoFRsB3" : {
      "email" : "kylebehiels@hotmail.com",
      "first_name" : "kyle",
      "games" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      },
      "last_name" : "behiels",
      "players" : {
        "hJuVfpGTJvRyP4qsA6xyyvgQDay1" : {
          "playerRegID" : "c_z_KWeWorU:APA91bHORVZqSph-HikfxtO2XjvMnwudIymORoSm9t3gupKZ1fFIZCLxGUbX5dsrYooHHpeEiPXhcXEMu5Eo5-nwF8bBjw-OTwSbn_rujTuPVaCDOXUKp9mzIYqeZq7SFMaWssZfyKj7"
        },
        "vlHVHcIetlZp7zS8mm6GcwoFRsB3" : {
          "playerRegID" : "cvZj3hb_zkk:APA91bEcmKlDlC5VKOI6wc1BvRI5mGgmWFA3QuTR3jH48l9fz565RhY2PEXE2GkXyhKXgb67qu7ieRlWF403q6rQPi0-xgGIbfvOkhGzopfyTFLNQg7ADgNHFAd1YfwwesbHjL5IHLZd"
        }
      },
      "practices" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      },
      "regid" : "cvZj3hb_zkk:APA91bEcmKlDlC5VKOI6wc1BvRI5mGgmWFA3QuTR3jH48l9fz565RhY2PEXE2GkXyhKXgb67qu7ieRlWF403q6rQPi0-xgGIbfvOkhGzopfyTFLNQg7ADgNHFAd1YfwwesbHjL5IHLZd",
      "workouts" : {
        "placeholder" : "placeholder"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual JSON that matches your code. You can easily get the JSON by clicking the the Export JSON link in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) of your project.

Comment: I added the json, thanks

Comment: OK. Thanks. If your `currentUserId` is `vlHVHcIetlZp7zS8mm6GcwoFRsB3`, you should be printing `"hJuVfpGTJvRyP4qsA6xyyvgQDay1" : {
          "playerRegID"....`. If that doesn't happen, can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem - as that may the fastest way to see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I am having some problems with jsbin. That is the output I am getting though. I will try to get jsbin working

Comment: Here is a gist I do not know if this will help you https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83df76052db04ea1ecc2de9739e1dbc8

Comment: A gist does not allow me to run the code. But also: don't just share your app with me, I'm not a remote debugger. Instead create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it contains a lot of useful information), which allows us to help you most efficiently.